# The span of two subsets

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question i trying to answer is to reduce a subset to just the reduce the subset to only the linear independent elements. Also to show that the Span(X)=Span(Y).

With X being the subset given and Y being the subset gained.

X:= $\bigg\{ \bigg(\begin{matrix}
  2 & 3 \\
  -4 & -5 \\
 \end{matrix} \bigg),
\bigg(\begin{matrix}
  -7 & 9 \\
  3 & -4 \\
 \end{matrix} \bigg), \bigg(\begin{matrix}
  -20 & 9 \\
  18 & 7 \\
 \end{matrix} \bigg) \bigg\}. $

Then by row reduction i get:

Y:= $\bigg\{ \bigg(\begin{matrix}
  2 & 3 \\
  -4 & -5 \\
 \end{matrix} \bigg),
\bigg(\begin{matrix}
  -7 & 9 \\
  3 & -4 \\
 \end{matrix} \bigg) \bigg\}.$

As the linearly independent elements. What does it mean by the Span(X)=Span(Y) this is the problem im having?

Comment: First, there's something wrong with your terminology: What do you mean by saying that $X$ is "the subspace given"? The trouble is that $X$ is not a subspace, it is just a set of three matrices.

Comment: Second, do you know the definition of "span"?

Comment: @LeeMosher sorry i meant the subset X. Got the definition of the span as The linear combinations of the elements X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably are working in the vector space of $2 \times 2$ matrices with real coefficients, under the operation of matrix addition.

As you say in the comments, $\text{Span}(X)$ is the set of linear combinations of the elements of $X$. So the equation $\text{Span}(X)=\text{Span}(Y)$ means that every linear combination of elements of $X$ is equal to a linear combination of elements of $Y$, and the other way around.

Since $Y \subset X$, it is obvious that every linear combination of elements of $Y$ is also a linear combination of elements of $X$.

In the other direction, let me use shorthand notation $X=\{M_1,M_2,M_3\}$ and $Y=\{M_1,M_2\}$. Suppose you could show that the matrix $M_3$ 
is a linear combination of elements of $Y$, perhaps 
$$M_3 = s M_1 + t M_2
$$
Then, for any linear combination of elements of elements of $X$, say $u M_1 + t M_2 + u M_3$, you can substitute for $M_3$ using the equation above, and combine terms, and you get a linear combination of elements of $Y$.

So, can you show that $M_3$ is a linear combination of $M_1$ and $M_2$?

Comment: yes, exactly what i needed already managed to do the linear combination just wasn't sure on the span part thanks.